# visual studio 2019 - direct link for references

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I ask your help for one stupid question (but useful for me)

I am no longer able to see the direct link to how many times one function is called above.
I therefore have to manually click find all the references and appear in a new window.

How do I enter this again?

[image: for example]

Comment: This feature is called Code Lens. Are you saying it is entirely gone? Did you switch Visual Studio editions?

Comment: yes, is completely gone. I have the professional version, upgraded from 2017 to 2019

Comment: Thank you Daniel B. Now it works. Code Lens was deactivated but I don't know the reason.

Comment: This is unlikely an issue caused by the upgrade to VS2019.  [It's more likely your code has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823805/codelens-not-showing-references/20828288#20828288).  Code Lens is indeed a feature of VS2019.  [Another Possible Workaround](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/f4e9ddcd-0274-409a-8b75-40c13435446a/codelens-does-not-work-on-visual-studio-2019)